# Jump Out of Loop When Error Occurs, Fix Error, Jump Back In Loop VBA

Tags: vba

Title is somewhat self explanatory. I am looking for a way to When encountering an error, jump out of the loop and perform an action to fix that error then begin again where it left off in the loop.

Basically I need an If On Error GoTo...else continue statement but I am pretty sure that does not exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: fix the error in the loop, there are many ways to check for errors without GoTo.

Comment: Show your code and pseudo code of you want to do. You can definitely use `On Error to Goto Label` and `Resume Next` code but you can look up examples of that online

Comment: `Resume` is the answer (or its variant `Resume Next`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick Error Handler and Return to Loop.

```
Dim x as Integer
For x = 1 to 10 Step 1
    On Error Goto HandleError
    'Do your code for each Loop
    NextLine:
Next x

Exit Sub
HandleError:
'Handle Error
'Clear the Error in case of new Error
'Return to Loop
Err.Clear
Resume NextLine
```

Edit: Added the Exit Sub before the handler to make sure you don't go into the handler after the loop is finished